# Crystal Reports if-then-else selection based on parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I have this crystal report, and I want to be able to use it to display every person in the table or display only those who owe money.

The parameter is called displayAll and is a boolean.
Basically I want this

```
if displayAll Then
   Show every person
else
   Show only When Balance is below 0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Record Selection Formula, say something like:

```
If {?DisplayAll} Then
    True
Else
    {Data.Balance} < 0;
```